# Is the Logitech Vantage USB Microphone for PS2/PS3 compatible with Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, audio-hardware

Is the [Logitech Vantage USB Microphone for PS2/PS3](http://www.logitech.com/en-gb/support/game-gear/3506) compatible with Wii?

I'd like to use one for Disney Sing It Wii game.

Comment: I'd suggest just trying it, but I assume you haven't bought the game yet. The only other game I know of that uses the mic are Guitar Hero and Rock Band.

Comment: Hi Chris. I have the game and found only the PS2/3 version of the microphone in store, which is also cheaper than the Wii version.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is Yes.

As stated [here](http://disneyinteractivestudios.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2927),

"All versions of the Logitech Vantage microphone (Retail/OEM for Playstation 2, Playstation 3, Wii, and Xbox 360) share the same Hardware ID (VID/PID), allowing all versions of the Vantage microphone to be used with any platform and game that supports this microphone, regardless if it is a Playstation 2, Playstation 3, Wii, or Xbox 360 Console."